# Set value array with a query

Tags: arrays, linq-to-sql

I want to set this Array with the result of ths Query but I can't. How do I do it ?

```
String[] q = (from p in MDB.aspnet_Memberships
                      where p.aspnet_User.aspnet_UsersInRoles.Single().aspnet_Role.RoleName.ToString() == GroupDDL.SelectedItem.ToString()
                      select new{p.UserId }).ToArray();
```

Exception :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'string[]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting a new anonymous object by using the braces.  When you do "`select new { p.UserID }`", the compiler creates a brand new object type.  You just want the userID's themselves, not a new object wrapping them up.  Try just

```
select p.UserId).ToArray();
```

as your select clause.